# How to test for DML errors in 'before' triggers (i.e. use of addError)

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

here's a brief rundown of the trigger I'm trying to test:

- this trigger is trying to put a cap on records with a certain lead source.  If someone selects this source and tries to save the record, it generates an error and tells them that they've hit the cap.
- the trigger works in the sandbox as advertised

So here's the code for the trigger:

```
trigger ProtectedCap on Lead (before update) {
 List<Lead> protectedTotal = [SELECT Owner_ID__c FROM Lead WHERE Status = 'Protected'];
    for (Lead myLead : Trigger.new) {
        if (myLead.Status == 'Protected' && protectedTotal.size() >= 100) {
                String protectedError = 'Protected Leads are at 100, please remove leads from Protected status to add.';
                myLead.addError (protectedError);
                }
            }
        }
```

For the test class, I generated leads and assigned the lead status that I'm trying to cap.  It runs and hits the error when it's supposed to, but of course the test thinks it's a bad error and fails out.  To be honest there's probably a number of other things wrong with it but I don't know enough to know enough.  Ya know?

Here's the test class:

```
@isTest
private class testNewLeadCap {
    static testMethod void validateNewLeadCap()
    {
        List<Lead> leads = new List<Lead>{};
        for(Integer i = 0; i <200; i++){
            Lead a = new Lead(FirstName = 'Test' + i, LastName = 'Testies' + i, Status = 'Protected');
            leads.add(a);
            }   
        test.startTest();
        insert leads;
        test.stopTest();    
}
}
```

Any assistance/insight would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Your trigger logic looks like it may not be correct in these circumstances:

- if the 100 limit has been reached, a change to any other field of one of the 'Protected' Leads will result in the error being reported incorrectly
- where any kind of bulk update is done, the 100 limit isn't correctly enforced; e.g. if there are no 'Protected' Leads and 300 Leads are bulk updated to 'Protected' no errors will be reported

This code should avoid both of these problems (and with a bit more work it could be made to only do the query when necessary rather than all the time):

```
trigger ProtectedCap on Lead (before update) {
    // Count Leads not being updated by this trigger
    Integer protectedCount = [
            SELECT Count()
            FROM Lead
            WHERE Status = 'Protected'
            AND Id not in :Trigger.newMap.keySet()
            ];
    // Check Leads that are being updated by this trigger
    for (Lead myLead : Trigger.new) {
        if (myLead.Status == 'Protected') {
            protectedCount++;
        }
        if (protectedCount >= 100) {
            myLead.addError('Protected Leads are at 100, '
                    + 'please remove leads from Protected status to add.');
        }
    }
}
```

That then allows a more precise test to be written:

```
@isTest
private class testNewLeadCap {
    static testMethod void increment() {
        insert createLeads(98);
        try {
            insert createLeads(5);
            System.assert(false, 'Exception expected');
        } catch (DmlException e) {
            System.assertEquals(100 - 98 + 5, e.getNumDml());
        }
    }
    static testMethod void allAtOnce() {
        try {
            insert createLeads(103);
            System.assert(false, 'Exception expected');
        } catch (DmlException e) {
            System.assertEquals(103 - 100, e.getNumDml());
        }
    }
    private static Lead[] createLeads(Integer n) {
        Lead[] leads = new Lead[] {};
        for(Integer i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            leads.add(new Lead(
                    FirstName = 'Test' + i,
                    LastName = 'Testies' + i,
                    Status = 'Protected'
                    ));
        }
        return leads;
    }
}
```

that would fail for the original trigger.

Comment: First off... huge thanks!  Ok so when I tried to save the trigger it gave me this error: :unexpected token: 'protected' at line 3 column 12

Comment: @user8030 probably a reserved word. Use a different name.

Comment: ok done... now I'm getting:

Illegal assignment from LIST<AggregateResult> to Integer at line 3 column 5

Comment: @user8030 I've edited the answer - try it now.

Comment: One item to note, the trigger is on `before update` and all of the unit test code examples are performing `insert` operations.

Comment: @user8030 Please consider Mark Pond's comment. Are you sure you don't want the logic to also run on insert? If your trigger covers both you should add more tests to cover both.

Comment: Ok so I ran all that and here's what I get now: Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: createLeads(Integer) at line 4 column 16

Comment: @user8030 Missing "static" I'll add.

Comment: ok first off again, thanks for all the help!  Now, it saved and I ran the test and it failed out. First error message is "System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: 3, Actual: 103" and the Stack Trace is "Class.testNewLeadCap.allAtOnce: line 17, column 1"

Comment: second error is "System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: 7, Actual: 5" with the Stack Trace: "Class.testNewLeadCap.increment: line 9, column 1"

Comment: @user8030 I feel bad about the compile errors but the logic errors I'll leave up to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
test.startTest();
try
{
  insert leads;
  System.assert(false, 'It should have failed out before reaching this point.');
}catch(Exception e)
{

}
test.stopTest();
```